# what fails in .fex file?

Tags: export, teradata

I'm developing a new .fex file copied from another one which works fine but when I run it, it notices me I have an error and I don't know where it is (column 39?)

This is the original .fex

```
.LOGTABLE ${DBSTG}.LT_TERMINALES_FINANCIADOS;

.set DBN to '${DBDWH}';
.set TBN to '${TABLE_IN_01}';
.set OFILE to '${DOWNDIR}/${FILE_OUT_01}';
.set FECHA_INICIO to '${FECHA_INICIO}';
.set FECHA_FIN to '${FechaActualCtrl}';

.BEGIN EXPORT SESSIONS 1;
.EXPORT OUTFILE &OFILE
OUTMOD ${COMDIR}/dlmt_vchar.so
FORMAT TEXT MODE RECORD;
LOCKING TABLE &DBN..&TBN FOR ACCESS
```

This is the new one

```
.LOGTABLE ${DBIFRS}.LT_${ERROR_TABLE};

.set DBN to '${DBIFRS}';
.set TBN to '${TABLE_ERROR}';
.set OFILE to '${DOWNDIR}/${FILE_OUT_01}';
.set EJECUCION to '${MOMENTO_EJECUCION}';

.BEGIN EXPORT SESSIONS 1;
.EXPORT OUTFILE &OFILE
OUTMOD ${COMDIR}/dlmt_vchar.so
FORMAT TEXT MODE RECORD;
LOCKING TABLE &DBN..&TBN FOR ACCESS
```

This is the error

```
     .LOGTABLE IFRSD.LT_IFRS15_LOG_ERRORES;
**** 08:20:28 UTY3403 Only one statement per line is allowed.  Extra characters
     were detected beginning in column '39'.
```

Column 39 is the 'R' in ERRORES

Comment: You've probably got some hidden characters in the line that appears blank (the second line in the new file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited in the remote machine adding an ENTER and saving, then it works, I don't know why... Maybe encoding